# Why do the roles of the Gods (of Destruction and Creation) and the Angels seem reversed?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragonball-super

In *Dragon Ball Super*, we see that Beerus (God of Destruction) gets overpowered and knocked out easily by Whis (Angel) in a single blow.

[image: Beerus defeated]

Does it make sense that Whis, an **Angel** and attendant of Beerus, a **God**, is stronger than a God? Shouldn't a God be stronger than all of the Angels?

Furthermore, there is the **Grand Priest** who stands still yet above all the other Angels, and by extension, the Gods of Destruction and Creation?

Comment: The properties of Angels, Gods, or other supernatural nonsense is just  whatever the author says. The terms may be being used in a non-standard or unexpected way, but that's the author's choice. Whether it "makes sense" or not is really not an answerable question, unless you can clarify.

Comment: As in every polytheistic universe there are several layers of godliness. The Kaios are Gods weaker than the Kaioshin weaker than the Gods of Destruction weaker than the angels weaker than the High Priest. In theory, Zeno is closer God like in capital G. How this will be in DBS compared to the High Priest is still to be seen.

Answer (score 2):

In the words of Edo from the MCU-"small g".
The way the hierarchy of godly authority works in the *Dragon Ball* universes,

- Grand Zeno
- Grand Priest
- Angels
- Gods of Destruction
- Kaoishins and apprentices - linked to Gods of Destruction, Supreme Kai, Zamasu, Old Kai
- Grand Kai - Goku vs pikkon in the final tournament!
- North, South, East, West - Kaios - usually you are dead to meet them
- King Yemma-decides if you go to heaven/hell/keep body
- world god-Dende-watches over the planet itself
- sub god-Korin, teaches mortals how to ascend in strength
- mortals-everyone else-Goku, Farmer with a shotgun

Angels in the traditional sense typically serve a "God". But here, they are not angels to the Gods of Destruction, they are angels to the great grand God Zeno.

Comment: Code blocks should be reserved for that, code. I fixed part of the formatting but am not sure whether some of the stuff in bullets should rather belong in separate bullets; please edit to clarify.

Comment: Thank you- was having trouble getting them to display as a list >.<

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a hard source other than observation/Manga/Anime but;
In the DB world, these "deities" serve a purpose, they seem to be watchers more than direct Gods as we would normally see them.  The Gods of Destruction on the otherhand are not deities like the Kai, Angels, Zeno, and anyone else I may have missed.  The Gods of Destruction all seem to be mortals who were chosen to fulfill a role within their Universe.  We see Toppo being trained to take over the role of God of Destro and from Manga sources, Belmod was also a Pride Troop member before becoming God of Destro.

It seems the function of the Angels is to observe.  They report back to Zeno on the happenings of their Universe.  And as we have seen Zeno can grow bored with governing multiple universes and simply make them disappear.  God of Destruction is an accurate name for the power these individuals wield, but likely over-sells them in the hierarchy of importance.  Especially if they are lazy at their jobs.